# How can I add my plugin window as a QGIS view Panels?

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, panel

I would like to add my plugin window to the list of panels in QGIS 3.18.
My goal is to attach my plugin window to one side of QGIS and it seems to be only possible for these listed panel windows.

[image]

Comment: Is your specific goal to attach the plugin to one side of the screen, or is it to add the plugin to the panels menu? If your goal is to attach the plugin window to one side of the screen, you can use a `dockwidget` UI type - [example](https://imgur.com/a/CpHhLqC).

Comment: Yes, That would solve my problem. Do you know how to switch my QDialog mainWindow into a QDockWidget?

Comment: See my answer below. It doesn't answer your original question about the QGIS view panels, but it is probably worth you rewording your question to be more in line with how to switch your QDialog mainWindow to a DockWidget. You will get better help that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you create your UI using QT Designer, you can make a new form and choose QDockWidget from the widgets dropdown and copy all your items across from your old form. You will have to update the UI initialisation in your code to the new type.

I tend to use the Plugin Builder plugin, there you can select DockWidget as your UI type.

[image]

[image]